# Mongodb query takes too long if no matches found

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I have a `posts` collection like bellow :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad249121c76fb096c0081e6"),
    "slug" : "5ad2491261324",
    "title" : "title",
    "content" : "content here",
    "tags" : [ 
        "tag1", 
        "tag2"
    ],
    "status" : 1,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-12T07:23:07.000Z"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5ad249111c76fb096c007dfd"),
    "url_id" : ObjectId("5ad249121c76fb096c0081e7"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-14T18:31:46.000Z"),
    "images" : [ 
        {
            "extension" : "jpg",
            "path" : "/medias/tests/4.jpg",
            "thumbnail" : "/medias/tests/4-th.jpg",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-14T18:31:46.000Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-14T18:31:46.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ad249121c76fb096c0081e8")
        }
    ]
}
```

The collection has text index on title.

When i execute bellow query :

```
db.getCollection('posts').find({title: /test/})
```

If there is at least one matches, the query executes very fast. But when it has not matches, takes too long to execute.

Why this happening?

**Edit**

I have 100m record in this collection.

Comment: Did you try with db.getCollection('posts').find( { title: { $regex: /test/ } } )

Comment: @jonhid Yes i tried it before. same result

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB facilitates creating text indexes on fields to search text contained into fields belonging to collection of MongoDB Database

According to description as mentioned into above question  collection has a text index on title field.

Hence to  search  a string value into title field  please try executing following find operation into MongoDB shell.

```
db.getCollection('posts').find({
        $text: {
            $search: 'test'
        })
```

According to documentation of MongoDB

> $text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with
>   a text index.

Comment: This query takes too long to execute in this case

Comment: Purpose of creating indexes is to speed up data fetching process from database collections. According to above description a collection has text index defined on title field and above query will perform a text search on indexed fields.